# Exec() jar file using PHP inside GODADDY server

Tags: php, executable, executable-jar, godaddy-api

[This is my folder structer. push.jar file is at httpdocs level and php file is at php folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Jfa.png)

This is the exec line which I used.

```
$token = $row2['dt_deviceToken'];
$title = "New Task";
$message = "You have a new task to do. Plesae check it";
exec("java -jar push.jar $token $title $message");
```

When I run this in **000webhosting free server**, it says according to security reasons they **can't execute the exec();** command.

Now I'm using **GODADDY paid server**. When I run this code it gives nothing event a warning message like 000webhosting gives. What could be the reason?

*Is exec() command is wrong. How to add absolute path of .jar file*

Comment: Make sure to check `output` and `error status` returned by `exec`, also json_encode() twice for arguments i.e. `$title`, `$message` and `$token`, as spaces can break command line.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, exec() not giving an output or error status. Do you mean by json_encode twice => json_encode(json_encode($title)) ?

Comment: thats right, you are in right track. Also make sure to use absolute path for `push.jar`, right from /home directory, `exec` might run from other dir

Comment: I added my folder structure. Please can you tell me how to add absolute path of `push.jar` file